# ErrorException Undefined variable $fleet when I try to store data to the database?

Tags: codeigniter

I have this issue when I try to store data to vehicles table which has relation with fleets table.

I don't get this error when I press add new vehicle but when I try to store data to the database.

> ErrorException Undefined variable $fleet

View:

```
   <div class="col-3">
   <label for="fleet_id" class="form-label"> Type </label>
       <select id="fleet_id" name="fleet_id" required="required"  class="form-control">
                             <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
                             <?php foreach ($fleet as $value) : ?>
                               <option value="<?= $value->id ?>"><?= $value->type ?></option>
                             <?php endforeach ?>
       </select> 
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
    public function new()
    {
        $data['fleet'] = $this->fleetModel->findAll();

        $data['module'] =    lang("Localize.fleet") ; 
        $data['title']  =    lang("Localize.add_vehicle") ;

        $data['pageheading'] = lang("Localize.add_vehicle");

        echo view($this->Viewpath.'\vehical/new',$data);
    }


    public function create()
    {
        
        $imgpath= array(); 
        $imgbus =  $this->request->getFileMultiple('busimg');
        

        if(!empty($imgbus))
            {
                foreach ($imgbus as $key => $imgvalue) {
                    if ($imgvalue->isValid() && ! $imgvalue->hasMoved() ) {
                        $busimag     = $this->imgaeCheck($imgvalue);
                        array_push($imgpath,$busimag);
                    }
                    
                }
            
            }
            
            
        
        $data= array(
            "fleet_id"=> $this->request->getVar('fleet_id'),
            "reg_no"=> $this->request->getVar('reg_no'),
        //  "engine_no"=> $this->request->getVar('engine_no'),
        //  "model_no"=> $this->request->getVar('model_no'),
        //  "chasis_no"=> $this->request->getVar('chasis_no'),
            "woner"=> $this->request->getVar('woner'),
            "woner_mobile"=> $this->request->getVar('woner_mobile'),
            "company"=> $this->request->getVar('company'),
            "status"=> $this->request->getVar('status'),
            "assign"=> $this->request->getVar('assign'),
            
        );

        if($this->validation->run($data, 'vehical'))
        {
            
            $vehicleid =  $this->vehiclModel->insert($data);

            if (!empty($imgpath)) {
                foreach ($imgpath as $key => $imgvalue) {
                    $storedata[ $key] = array(
                                            "vehicle_id"=> $vehicleid,
                                            "img_path"=> $imgvalue,
                                            );
                }


                $this->vImageModel->insertBatch($storedata);
            }
            return redirect()->route('index-vehicle')->with("success","Data Save");
            
        }
        
        
        else
        {
            $data['validation'] = $this->validation;

            $data['module'] =    lang("Localize.fleet") ; 
            $data['title']  =    lang("Localize.add_vehicle") ;

            echo view($this->Viewpath.'\vehical/new',$data);

        }
        
    }
```

Comment: In the `create` function, you're missing a `fleet` key in the `$data` array.

Comment: you didn't provide the vehclModel model which might be looking for a $fleet variable.